# Converting Json to Object in Java/Spring using Exchange()

Tags: java, json, spring

I was using

```
 ResponseEntity<List<item>> res = restTemplate.exchange(
                "http://localhost:8080/page",
                HttpMethod.GET,
                null,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<item>>() {});
```

for one of my applications but since I made the rest service, it only returned 2 items via Json. My question is, I'm trying to get the weather and the api I'm using returns:

```
{"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"weather":    [{"id":741,"main":"Fog","description":"fog","icon":"50n"},{"id":701,"main":"Mist","description":"mist","icon":"50n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":278.47,"pressure":1012,"humidity":100,"temp_min":277.15,"temp_max":279.15},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":1},"clouds":{"all":75},"dt":1479864000,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5093,"message":0.0311,"country":"GB","sunrise":1479886350,"sunset":1479916868},"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200}
```

That's alot of JSON, so I was wondering do I have to make a class that contains all those objects with setters/getters (a coord field, id, description, weather, name, etc...), or can I just make an object with like a coord object and weather object and have only those fields mapped in?

Thanks for any advice.

EDIT:

Maybe it would have something to do with the ignoreUnknown = true properties of the @JsonIgnoreProperties tag?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with it later. If you care only for parts of the response, why bother keeping them around? If you'll need them, you can map the JSON to a class, or just keep the JSON around and access the fields from that directly. For the sake of readability, I'd transform the JSON into a class, though.

Comment: I don't need them. But Im using the openweather.com api, I can't (or can I somehow?) edit the response, it just returns all of this when you enter in a city. All I really need is a few of the fields (like weather":[{"id":741,"main":"Fog","description":"fog"}), its just for a simple project I'm doing. I just didnt want to have to make an object with all those fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need just two classes to set them getter and setter class. Your "weather" variable is just List, anothers are static variables. I would do it like this:

```
public class Weather {

  private Long id;

  private String name;

  private Long cod;

  private coordLong string;

  private coordLat string;

  priva... baseStations, cloudsAll, windSpeed, mainTemp...

  private List<WeatherList> weatherList;

  ...
  //getters setters
```

Comment: yea but it just seems theres so much useless stuff in there. wind has a speed, a direction, "main" has a temp, pressure, humidity, min temp, max temp, theres a set for clouds, sunrise, sunset, stuff I don't need

Comment: you have to add just your usable variable to your class. not all of them are mandatory

Comment: thanks thats what I did and I think I got it. The variable name has to be the same as the field name in the json right? Like I just made a object with a 'base' string field and it correctly got set to 'stations'.

Comment: you can make the variable names same for clarity, you are creating new object it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map all the variables just make a single Model class and map your response, like this

```
public class WeatherData{

private Coordinate coord;
private List<Weather> weather;

//Getters and setters setCoord(),getCoord().setWeather(),getWeather().

public class Coordinate{

    private Double lon;
    private Double lat;
    //Getters and Setters
}

public class Weather{

    private Integer id;
    private String main;
    private String description;
    private String icon;

    //Getters and setters
}

//Remaining fields

}
```

and then map your json like this

```
//json is your response in String format
Gson gson = new Gson();
WeatherData weatherData = gson.fromJson(json,WeatherData.class);
//handle exception here
```

and then get any variable value like this

```
lat = weatherData.getCoord().getLat();
```